# Allowing only x Position to change with Time using Kinect Body Joint Position in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect

Guys I am making an endless runner game which will be controlled with body position.

I'm trying to move character left or right (x-axis) with my body position by using Kinect sensor. The character is free to move forward (z-axis) with `Time.deltaTime`. The character has `CharacterController` and script attached. The code is below for movement:

```
CharacterController controller;
KinectManager kinectManager;
float speed = 5.0f
Vector3 moveDir;
void Update()
{
    moveDir = Vector3.zero;
    moveDir.z = speed;
    moveDir.x = kinectManager.instance.BodyPosition * speed;

    //controller.Move(moveDir * Time.deltaTime);

    controller.Move(new Vector3 (moveDir.x, 0, moveDir.z * Time.deltaTime));
}
```

This statement `controller.Move(moveDir * Time.deltaTime);`  keeps moving character to the left or right because x position is being incremented with `Time.deltaTime` so I wanted to restrict that and I changed that to `controller.Move(new Vector3 (moveDir.x, 0, moveDir.z * Time.deltaTime));`.

Now whats happening is the character is stuck at the same position. I can move left or right with body position but cannot move forward. What am I missing here?

Please help.

Comment: can you elaborate on what you want to achieve? Do you want the character to move forward on the z - axis at a constant rate over time? I don't understand what "z position to change with time".

Comment: moveDir.z = speed;
Why you used this statement . It looks illogical to me . How could assign a speed variable to the axis parameter. ?

Comment: @CowNecromancer yes exactly. I want to move the character in forward direction in constant speed but at the same time i want to change the x position without time affecting it.

Comment: What does `controller.Move` do exactly? What type is `controller`? Let me show code.

Comment: @HamzaTahir Actually I can and its working fine. The thing is im passing whole vector in CharacterController.

Comment: @HeejaeKim its Unity's CharacterController. Its declared like this `CharacterController controller;`

Comment: Try this.
`moveDir.z += speed * Time.deltaTime;
controller.Move(new Vector3(moveDir.x, 0, moveDir.z));`

Comment: Do you understand the use of Time.deltaTime? This variable does not increase over time, It is used to make it sure  movement is consistent as update function updates at irregular intervals. There is not reason why you would want to change direction along the x-axis at irregular intervals.

Comment: @CowNecromancer Yes I know. I just want to move object on x-axis without time and I think we can do that.

Comment: Then you shouldn't be moving it with the update function. Also where are these x-axis values coming from can you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

## Indentifying issues

First try to watch you axis carefully that where is your gameobject y axis because you are assigning 0 value to it . The below code will help you find the issue and resolve it .

## Solution

```
void Update()
{
    if (controller.isGrounded)
    {
        // We are grounded, so recalculate
        // move direction directly from axes

        moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection);
        moveDirection = moveDirection * speed;

        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        {
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
        }
    }

    // Apply gravity
    moveDirection.y = moveDirection.y - (gravity * Time.deltaTime);

    // Move the controller
    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: As I said I don't want to move object with time on x-axis. I know where are my axes and I only want to move it to z-axis.

Comment: Your solution is simple which i have already. I don't want that. Please read the question again. Thanks.

Comment: The code was just posted to identify the issue . I cant tell solution until i dnt have proper code information because in unity there are plenty of things to being seen . In frustration you have given me a down vote where i am trying to help you to identify the issue , And that explains everything .